# Chrome / Chromium Edge & styling fields with autocomplete

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

In a simple login form, I'm using inputs with a larger font. In Chrome (and obviously Edge/Chromium), when the form is displayed and the autocomplete is active, values are shown with a regular font (font-size & font-family, probably others, too) :

[image]

The moment a click occurs (anywhere in the document), the inputs instantly change to the proper font size:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Are you talking about a placeholder? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and show us the relevant code, preferably as a runnable snippet.

Comment: No, it is the value itself that Chrome autofills when displaying the page. I have found it a bit difficult to create an example, as it requires Chrome to save and autofill the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used to be able to customize it by `input:-webkit-autofill::first-line`, but it was removed due to [a security concern](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1035058). In short, now we cannot force the custom font of the autocompleted content to be displayed immediately, unless there's a click.

Comment: Thank you. So... it can't be done, unless Chrome changes.

Comment: @stefanu Yes, but you can also send feedback in the browser to make the Dev Team aware of it. Let's hope there will be an alternative.

Comment: done and, funny fact, in the process I found an issue in the issue reporting dialog box : the layout is broken when the screenshot is very wide (3xHD for me)